# Covariant Derivative for a Graph

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

The graph of a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by $\sigma(u,v)=(u,v,f(u,v))$. Let$X=d\sigma(e_1)$ and $Y=d\sigma(e_2)$ be two vector fields on $\sigma(u,v)$.

The covariant derivative can be calculateed with
\begin{align*}
        \nabla_X Y = \Big(D_X Y^1 + \sum_{i,j} \Gamma_{ij}^1 X^i Y^j \Big) \sigma_u + \Big(D_X Y^2 + \sum_{i,j} \Gamma_{ij}^2 X^i Y^j \Big) \sigma_v,
\end{align*}
with $X=X^1\sigma_u+X^2\sigma_v$ and $Y=Y^1\sigma_u+Y^2\sigma_v.$

My ideas:
I already calculated the Christoffel symbols:
\begin{align*}
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
            \Gamma_{11}^1 & \Gamma_{12}^1 & \Gamma_{22}^1\\
            \Gamma_{11}^2 & \Gamma_{12}^2 & \Gamma_{22}^2\\
        \end{array} \right)=\frac{1}{1+f_u^2+f_v^2}\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
            f_uf_{uu}-f_u^2f_vf_{uv} & 0 & f_uf_{vv}+f_vf_{uv}+f_v^3f_{uv}\\
            f_vf_{uu}+f_uf_{uv}+f_u^3f_{uv} & 0 & f_vf_{vv}-f_uf_v^2f_{uv} \\
        \end{array} \right)\\
    \end{align*}
I know that $d\sigma$ is the Jacobian
\begin{align}
    d\sigma=(\sigma_u,\sigma_v)=\begin{pmatrix}
    1&0\\0&1\\f_u&f_v
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Is then $X^1=Y^2=1$ and $X^2=Y^1=0$ and therefore $\nabla_X Y=0$?

Comment: I do not believe your Christoffel symbol formulas.